# wysiwyg remove markup

Tags: javascript, editor, wysiwyg

I am trying to learn javascript and jquery, as projects i have mage image editor and now wysiwyg editor, the problem i am having is removing markup from selected text

this is what i have so far

```
 function removemarkup() {
  var range = window.frames['textEditor'].getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
  var selectionContents = range.extractContents();
  alert(selectionContents);
   var selectedText = selectionContents.toString();  
  alert(selectedText);
}
```

all this does is replace the selected text any ideas

Thank you in advance

http://www.html5imageeditor.co.uk/texteditor/index.html

Comment: Me too. Can you give steps to reproduce the undesired behavior? Maybe browser specific? I use chrome

Comment: Can you detail more your question please? What is the desired behavior? What is actually happening?

Comment: Maybe you're looking for `document.execCommand('removeFormat')`?

Comment: i am using Firefox at the moment this is what i am after document.execCommand('removeFormat') but it does not work on my editor so i would like an alternative way thank you

Comment: @tuckbloor it should work in Firefox if the selected text is inside of an element with `contenteditable` ... see about halfway down [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Rich-Text_Editing_in_Mozilla). Here's a demo - http://jsfiddle.net/dz6fc/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function removemarkup() {
  var range = window.frames['textEditor'].getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
  var selectionContents = range.startContainer.data;
  alert(selectionContents);
}
```

Comment: thank you that gets the selected text what i would like to is remove the tags around it ecxeccommand does not work for me thank you for the help

Comment: @tuckbloor I'm on my way to the airport for my flight home. I will follow up on this as soon as I get a chance